# setting starting point of state before any move and the move path

Tags: optaplanner

i am trying to learn optaplanner. i went over the docs and examples. taking the nqueen example, i am trying to change a little bit the problem by replacing it to knight instead of queen.

1. i want to set the first knight in fixed position, like col0#row0. this should be the starting point without changing it. how can i do that?
2. i want to specify the legal move path of a knight (more complex from the queen) - where is the best place to implement it? to specify it on a custom move? on the knight object itself?

appreciate any assistance

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse a "chess move" with a "Local Search move". A chess move signals the valid places a chess piece can attack. A Local Search move is a way to go from one Solution state to another Solution state by changing 1 or more variables.

To change the Queens into a Knights, simply take the nqueens example and adjust the scoreRules.drl so it's a hard constraint match if 2 chess pieces are a knight's pattern away from each other.

Notice that with those changes, the Local Search move will still simply change the row of a Knight. Also, unlike in nqueens, the column could become a planning variable too, because multiple Knights can be on the same column without attacking each other.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer.
understood the differences but how can i set a knight always on col0#row0 and move only the other knights?

the problem i want to solve is:
traverse with a knight over the all chessboard without passing on the same square already passed on.
i thought to solve it as 64 knights on a chessboard (8*8) and the constraints are cover all the chessboard and not to pass on the same square more than once.

Comment: see "immutable planning entities" in the docs and/or [this blog article](http://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2013/10/11/WillSkynetControlOurSchedule.html)

Comment: or add a hard constraint that there must be a knight on (0,0). But immovable planning entities is prettier.